# access persistent volume in kubeflow from different components

Tags: persistent-volumes, kubeflow, kubernetes-pvc, kubeflow-pipelines

I am adding persistent volume claim to my kubeflow pipeline components and I would like to be able to access the volume from the different components so I can store data in it and retreive it from other components.

1. Volume definition:

```
vop = kfp.dsl.VolumeOp(
        name="create-pvc",
        resource_name="my-pvc",
        modes=kfp.dsl.VOLUME_MODE_RWO,
        size=volume_size
    )
```

2. Mount volume to components:

```
comp1.add_pvolumes({"/mnt'": vop.volume})
comp2.add_pvolumes({"/mnt'": comp1.pvolume})
```

3. I create some data in comp1 and want to read it from comp2

```
# data read from external source
data=some_data_frame_readed_from_gcs

# data pickled to volume
path = os.path.abspath("data")
with open(path, 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(data, f)
print("PATH: {}".format(path))
# output path is: "/mnt/data"

# Now I try to read it from comp2
with open(path, 'rb') as f:
    df = pickle.load(f)
```

4. this is the error code showing in kubeflow pipeline:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/mnt/data'
```

Answer (score 2):

Is there a particular reason you want to use volumes?
KFP has built-in data passing mechanisms (See the [Data passing for Python](https://github.com/Ark-kun/kfp_samples/blob/65a98da/2019-10%20Kubeflow%20summit/104%20-%20Passing%20data%20for%20python%20components/104%20-%20Passing%20data%20for%20python%20components.ipynb))

I'd advice to use the built-in data-passing methods if your data is  <10GB in size.

Volumes are less supported and make components not portable. Volumes are not supported on Vertex AI Pipelines for example.

Comment: Thanks! I want to try PVC to be able to allocate memory for large data use cases. Also to note I am getting this error when passing 1.5 GB data:
"This step is in Error state with this message: failed to save outputs: Request entity too large: limit is 3145728 "

Comment: This can happen in *upstream* component when your *downstream* component tries to consume big data as a command-line value. See the tutorial I've linked. It has examples for both small data passing (as values) and bigger data passing (as files).